# What filter do I need? Want to keep high frequency values only

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I am asking this question because I am not quite sure which filter I should be using.

Mine is simply a signal made up of discrete values as such `s = [1 2 2 2 3 4 2 4 3 4 5 3 2 3 3]`. Then I would like, per window size, a filtered signal. So e.g. if I use a window size of 5 for `s` then I would get; `s_filtered = [2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3]`. Hence I want to keep the values that are of the highest frequency in each block. For indices 0:4 (window size 5) the values of highest frequency is 2, so I want my "filtered" signal (if that is indeed the correct terminology) to have 2 in all indices 0:4 for the "filtered" signal.

Currently I am using just a median filter, but I do no think this is the correct approach.

Here is some python code to demonstrate what I am doing (but as said, which I think is wrong).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab *
from scipy.signal import medfilt

test = np.random.randint(10, size=1000)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(15,5))
ax1.plot(test)
ax1.plot(medfilt(test,[99]),'r')
plt.show()
```

[image: Random data with median filtered signal in red.]

Where the red line is the filtered signal for a window size of 99.

**SOLUTION:**

```
import itertools
import collections

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

s = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3]

list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(collections.Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0],5) for x in grouper(s,5)))
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think what you're after is a "moving average"... though that normally means the mean, not the most common value (aka "mode").

Comment: A moving average is a function of nearby samples. Mean, median and mode are all variations on the concept of "average".

Comment: @alexis I see, but I am not really looking at averages; I want to populate arrays with values that statistically occur most often per window. Does average really relate to this?

Comment: The most common value in a sample is called the "mode", and yes it's a kind of "average". See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29#Comparison_of_mean.2C_median_and_mode) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grouper` function from [*itertools recipes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to group your array based on a specified length and then find the most common item using `collections.Counter.most_common()` method and use `itertools.repeat` to repeat your item 5 time and at last chain the repeated objects with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` :

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Demo :

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0],5) for x in grouper(s,5)))
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```